# How to get a Docker container's IP address, located within a bridge network, from a windows host?

Tags: mysql, docker

A bridge network has been created in docker using the following:

```
docker network create blognetwork
```

And a container has been created in that network with the following:

```
docker run --name=blogdb --network=blognetwork -p 3306:3306 -e --bind-address=0.0.0.0 -e=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -detach mysql
```

How do I access the ip address of the new container, within the "blognetwork", from a windows host?

How do I get the ip address of the form X.X.X.X, on its own? I know I can use the following to get a large json output with this data in it:

```
docker network inspect blognetwork
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get directly the ip by using docker inspect and a proper format:

```
docker inspect containerId --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'
```

More info in the [Docker documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#examples)

Answer (score 8):

You can get directly the IP address by using docker inspect. Docker inspect provides detailed information on constructs controlled by Docker.

Modern Docker client syntax is:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

Old Docker client syntax is:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container_name_or_id
```

These commands will return the Docker container's IP address.

If you are on Windows, use double quotes " instead of single quotes ' around the curly braces.

For more information [Docker inspect documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#examples).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command to get container information along with container IP.

`docker inspect 'ContainerID'`

Answer (score 1):

Since you ran

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 ...
```

you should access the service via port 3306 using your host's DNS name or IP address.

In the very specific case where you're at a shell prompt or browser URL entry on the machine where you ran `docker run`, assuming you're not using Docker Machine or Docker Toolbox, in this case and in this case only, you can use `localhost:3306` to access the container.  Never ever use `localhost` for anything else around Docker unless you're totally clear what it means.  (If you ever start writing a question that uses the words "...the localhost of..." then localhost isn't what you want.)

If you are trying to reach this container from another container, since you ran

```
docker run --name=blogdb --network=blognetwork ...
```

you can use the name `blogdb` as a host name, and Docker provides an internal DNS service that can resolve it to something that will reach the container.

You never want the Docker-internal IP address, and should never run `docker inspect` to try to find it.  The two biggest problems with it are that it's unreachable from off-host and that it changes when the container is deleted and recreated.

Comment: You never want the Docker-internal IP address, and should never run docker inspect to try to find it.  +1 for that. 
Mapping the ports back to the host system, should be enough to access the service running on the container.